# How to solve $e^{5k}-e^{-5k}=3$?

Tags: substitution

$$e^{5k}-e^{-5k}=3$$
How do I solve for k using the substitution $y=e^{5k}$ by making it into a quadratic equation?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines) run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Comment: For example, what did you get after setting $y=e^{5k}$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: recall that $e^{-5x}=\frac{1}{e^{5x}}\equiv \frac1y$
where the last equivalence is using your substituion.

From here you should know how to go about.

Super Hint: Using the substitution together with the first hint we obtain
$$y-\frac1y=3$$
and multiplying with $y$ we obtain
$$y^2-1=3y$$
Now you definitely need to solve this one yourself (and keep in mind that $y=0$ cannot be a solution, although in this case it is anyway not a candidate)

Comment: could you please complete the answer please

Comment: i know its 1 /y but i'm not getting my answer right

Comment: @jcupslyu Please see [Why do some answerers prefer full solutions to hints for homework and homework-like questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4300/272831) and [Homework questions - avoiding giving a complete solution](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/415/272831).

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{5k}-e^{-5k}=3\Longleftrightarrow (e^{5k})^2- 3e^{-5k} -1 = 0\Longleftrightarrow  X^2 -3X -1 =0 $$
With $X=e^{5k}$,
$$\Delta = 13$$

Then $$X=\frac{3 \pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$$

But $e^{5k} =X>0$ and $\frac{3 -\sqrt{13}}{2}<0$ so $$X=\frac{3 +\sqrt{13}}{2}$$

hence $$k = \frac15 \ln\left( \frac{3 +\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)$$